# Solr 6.2.1 - Bad Request (400) - Invalid content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded; (ManagedSynonymsFilterFactory)

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr6

Using following query to add a new synonym mapping, you can PUT/POST a single mapping. **(ManagedSynonymFilterFactory)**

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary 
'{"mad":["angry","upset"], "happy": ["smiling", "jolly"]}' 
"localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/schema/analysis/synonyms/english"
```

and getting the following response with error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: happy
curl: (3) [globbing] bad range in column 2
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 6
{
"responseHeader":{
"status":500,
"QTime":111},
"error":{
"msg":"Bad Request",
"trace":"Bad Request (400) - Invalid content type application/x-www-form- 
urlencoded; only application/json is supported.\r\n\tat only application/json is supported.\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.rest.RestManager$ManagedEndpoint.parseJsonFromRequestBody(RestManager.java:407)\r\n\tat 
org.apache.solr.rest.RestManager$ManagedEndpoint.put(RestManager.java:340)\r\n\tat org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doHandle(ServerResource.java:447)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.doConditionalHandle(ServerResource.java:359)\r\n\tat org.restlet.resource.ServerResource.handle(ServerResource.java:1044)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.resource.Finder.handle(Finder.java:236)\r\n\tat org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)\r\n\tat org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:639)\r\n\tat org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)\r\n\tat org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)\r\n\tat org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.engine.application.StatusFilter.doHandle(StatusFilter.java:140)\r\n\tat org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)\r\n\tat org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:202)\r\n\tat org.restlet.engine.application.ApplicationHelper.handle(ApplicationHelper.java:75)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.Application.handle(Application.java:385)\r\n\tat org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)\r\n\tat org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422)\r\n\tat org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:639)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)\r\n\tat org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.routing.Router.doHandle(Router.java:422)\r\n\tat org.restlet.routing.Router.handle(Router.java:639)\r\n\tat org.restlet.routing.Filter.doHandle(Filter.java:150)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.routing.Filter.handle(Filter.java:197)\r\n\tat org.restlet.engine.CompositeHelper.handle(CompositeHelper.java:202)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.Component.handle(Component.java:408)\r\n\tat org.restlet.Server.handle(Server.java:507)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerHelper.handle(ServerHelper.java:63)\r\n\tat org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:143)\r\n\tat 
org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet.service(ServerServlet.java:1117)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:566)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:199)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:74)\r\n\tat 
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:266)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:208)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)\r\n\tat 
org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\n",
"code":500}}
```

I was following an example in Solr document but still got this error. Why this error occured even when I'm following each step from the doc. I'm using **Solr 6.2.1 on Windows**

document for above example: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/managed-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

I have seen such errors many times. I cannot pinpoint the right issue right now, but it has nothing to do with Solr, but with Curl.

As you are in windows, I guess you are using cmd, I strongly advise you set up [WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL) and do all curl-ing to solr in a ubuntu (or whatever linux you prefer) terminal, you will be able to use all snippets from the doc/examples without converting them to Windows world, and your life will be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `""` around parameters under cmd in Windows, not `''`. To escape the `"` inside the JSON string, use `""`, or add the JSON content to a file and use `-d "@request.json"` instead, avoiding the need to escape anything explicitly.

Comment: This worked for techproducts example. But now I'm trying this to implement with a Core that I build with command "solr create -c test". This command created a core with a default "data_driven_schema_config". but curl command can only be used with techproducts. what changes should I do now so that I can use curl command on my "test" core. I've already added managedSynonymsFilterFactory to managed-schema. added _rest_managed.json and _schema_analysis_synonyms_english.json files to conf folder. everything is working fine except the curl command. Not getting any response on curl command.

Comment: Please ask a new question in that case with the relevant information, but in general - you shouldn't have to change or add the files manually if you're using the API. That's what the API is for.

Answer (score 0):

Solve your problem with the below example

**Error Request:** curl -X PUT -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '["foo"]' "http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/schema/analysis/stopwords/
english"

**Correct Request:** curl -X POST -H "Content-type:application/json" --data-binary "["foo"]" "http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/schema/analysis/stopwords/english"

Note: Simple replace ' with " in the request to make it simple.